# Erro em Python2

Tags: python, array, python-2.7

Estou praticando utilizando Python 2, porém não sei o motivo deste erro. Segue abaixo o meu código com o erro. E numpy eo scipy estão instalados, pois quando eu dou o import não aparece mais nenhum erro.

```
vaca1=    [1,1,0]    
vaca2=    [1,1,0]    
vaca3=    [1,1,0]    
cavalo4= [1,1,1]    
cavalo5= [0,1,1]    
cavalo6= [0,1,1]    
dados=[vaca1,vaca2,vaca3,cavalo4,cavalo5,cavalo6]    
marcacoes= [1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1]    
misterioso= [1, 1, 1]
```

...

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

modelo= MultinomialNB()
modelo.fit(dados, marcacoes)
MultinomialNB(alpha=1.0, class_prior=None, fit_prior=True)
print(modelo.predict(misterioso))
```

Aqui esta o erro:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 1, in 
>         File "C:\tools\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py", line
>   66, in predict
>           jll = self._joint_log_likelihood(X)
>         File "C:\tools\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py", line
>   724, in _joint_log_likelihood
>           X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr')
>         File "C:\tools\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py",
>   line 410, in check_array
>           "if it contains a single sample.".format(array))
>       ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
>       array=[1 1 1].
>       Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single
>   sample.

Comment: A msg de erro diz q misterioso deve ser uma matriz 2D, então deveria ser: `misterioso=[[1],[1],[1]]`, fazendo essa correção esse erro não ocorrerá mais, mas é provável que outro erro ocorra. Faz tempo que não uso scikit, mas tem algo errado no seu modelo de dados, o ideal seri q vc explicasse o objetivo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[[TL;DR]](https://repl.it/LIrt/1)

Tente assim:

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
import numpy as np

vaca1=    [1,1,0]    
vaca2=    [1,1,0]    
vaca3=    [1,1,0]    
cavalo4= [1,1,1]    
cavalo5= [0,1,1]    
cavalo6= [0,1,1]   

dados = np.array([vaca1,vaca2,vaca3,cavalo4,cavalo5,cavalo6])
marcacoes= np.array([1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1])
misterioso = np.array([[1, 1, 1]])

modelo= MultinomialNB()
modelo.fit(dados, marcacoes)
MultinomialNB(alpha=1.0, class_prior=None, fit_prior=True)
print(modelo.predict(misterioso))
[-1]
```

[Veja funcionando no repl.it.](https://repl.it/LIrt/1)

Comment: Obrigado funcionou, será que você pode explicar assim por cima o porquê do meu erro.

Comment: Beemm "Por cima": A função espera um array 2D (bidimensional) mas vc estava enviando um unidimensional, a propria msg de erro diz isso. Neses casos o melhor que vc pode fazer é tentar adaptar o seu contexto a um exemplo da documentação, [veja esse.](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html)

Comment: Valeu, também estava procurando por isso e funcionou.